# "n" number of API calls in the sequentially order in the Node.js?

Tags: node.js

How to call "n" number of API calls in the sequentially order(each API response as input parameter for next API call) in the Node.js?

Comment: you should use async await or promise to manage order sequentially.

Comment: Thank you @Dipakchavda. Could you please share sample example code for the promise?

Comment: Please post some of your tries or just google it. There are hundreds of examples online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, review below example of promise in which you may find that it will execute synchronously as your requirement.

```
let firstPromise = (() => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve("first promise");
  });
});

let secondPromise = (() => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve("second promise");
  });
});

let thirdPromise = (() => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve("third promise");
  });
});

let fourthPromise = (() => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve("fourth promise");
  });
});


firstPromise()
  .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return secondPromise();
  })
  .then((res) => {   
      console.log(res);
      return thirdPromise();
  })
  .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return fourthPromise();
  })
  .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    throw new Error(err);
  });
```